# jQuery parent and child selector

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use this selector it its not working for me

```
var pr = $(this).closest('fieldset');
$( pr + ' > .given option:selected').remove().appendTo(pr + ' > .allowed');
```

I get this error

```
Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]
```

why does this not work the way I expect it to ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your code is that pr is not a string. Therefor you cannot add it to the rest of your selector.

This should work:

```
$('.given option:selected', pr).remove().appendTo($('.allowed', pr));
```

This will force jQuery to search in the context of pr

Comment: i had to wrap the appendTo contents like this $('.given option:selected', pr).remove().appendTo($('.allowed', pr));

Comment: Sorry, missed that one. Edited my response now.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing jQuery objects and selectors.

the `pr` variable becomes a javascript (jQuery) object after this line:

```
var pr = $(this).closest('fieldset');
```

And then you are appending this object to a new selector, which is not how it should be done. If I understand your intent right, try the following:

```
var pr = $(this).closest('fieldset');
pr.filter('.given option:selected').remove().appendTo(pr.filter('.allowed'));
```